# Django User Authentification

Tags: java, django, authentication, django-login

I am writing a piece of java code to login to django based website with the following code. 
But it returns an 403 error

```
[18/Feb/2014 15:16:36] "POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2282
```

Anyone gets some idea of how to solve this? 
Thanks a lot in advance!

```
private String baseUrl = "http://localhost:9999";    
boolean result = false;
try {
        URL url = new URL(baseUrl + "/accounts/login/");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoInput(true);
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        String formParameters = "csrfmiddlewaretoken="
                + para + "&username="
                + "name" + "&password="
                + "pwd" + "&next=";

        System.out.println(formParameters);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(formParameters, "UTF-8"));
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        if(con.getResponseCode() == 302){
            result = true;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

return result;
```

Comment: That can't be your full code, as `para` - the value for the CSRF token - is undefined. Where is it coming from?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for your reply. CSRF token is defined in Django Framework, I just use it as the parameters to transfer to Django framework.

Comment: But where are you getting the value for it *in this code*?

Comment: @DanielRoseman that is the parameter that i transfer from the function where i call this code. Thanks Daniel, it seems like that it is because of csrf problem, so then i added csrf_exempt, and it works. But maybe you can give some suggestions on other methods except csrf_exempt to avoid 403 forbidden problem?

Comment: No I can't, because you won't tell me how you're getting that parameter. It needs to come from the value in the cookie set by the original request to Django.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I was troubleshooting this same problem for a while now and I feel I need to share this. This is probably too late, but may be useful for all those in the future that need some help with a similar issue.

1. Request the login page and Django will set your cookie:

   ```
   URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9999");
   HttpURLConnection client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   client.setDoInput(true);
   client.connect();
   inputStream = client.getInputStream(); // open input stream
   //read input
   StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
   IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, "UTF-8");
   String string = writer.toString();
   //NOTE (look for this under this code section)
   String cookie= client.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie").get(0);
   client.disconnect();
   ```

*NOTE*: Your header values are stored in `HashMap<String,List<String>>`, I used `get(0)` because in my experience the list for the "Set-Cookie" only contains 1 value, so I get index 0 which in this example contains this:

```
"csrftoken=FwYSncufKaCZjxLWGUPq7ORZRvTXIxkU; expires=Sun, 09-Jul-2017 18:23:09 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/ 1"
```

As you can see it contains the csrf cookie. 
Now you need to do two more things:

1. Put the previous cookie into your next url request properties
2. You need to put your csrf token value (in this example "FwYSncufKaCZjxLWGUPq7 ORZRvTXIxkU", you can get this value with [regex](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)) into your POST parameters.

Here is some code to that:

```
    url = new URL(LOGIN_URL);
    client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    client.setDoInput(true);
    client.setDoOutput(true);
    client.setRequestMethod("POST");
    //set cookie to the previous cookie that has the correct csrf token
    client.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
    //set up the form params for the POST
    String formParameters = "csrfmiddlewaretoken="
            + csrf + "&username="
            + "name" + "&password="
            + "pwd";

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
            client.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(formParameters.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
    client.connect();
    inputStream = client.getInputStream();
    //read return input from the django server
    writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, "UTF-8");
    string = writer.toString();
```

Hope this helps for all those in the future!